# Variable speed for a 4.5 V - 12 V DC hobby motor

Tags: motor, motor-controller, speed

How can I vary the speed of a 4.5 V - 12 V DC hobby motor?

This motor will run a set of conveyors to simulate a steel mill operation. The motor has small gears to run the conveyor, but I need to be able to slow it down so the school kids don't go wild with it.

I would like a slider type of control as I am using hobby syringes with colored water to move the slide. This will act like hydraulic cylinders and at the end of the 4 conveyors the little blocks on the conveyor will fall into a bin and raise a gate to let the oxobot out and travel around.

I am not very good with electrical circuits, very good in hydraulics and pneumatics. Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the power rating of your motor?

Comment: easy: give it less power. you can reduce the volts or deliver full volts some of the time (pwm)

Comment: I'm sure that a hobby shop will have a motor controller for your DC hobby motor. Why not just bring in your motor and buy a controller? Or if you don't have the motor yet, buy both? (They probably also can be found with an interface for a micro, if that's your need.)

Comment: Yeah, I bet they have a lm317 based DC regulator circuit for small power DC motors, complete with heatsink for less than $10. No need for anything more complicated.

Comment: Answers have suggested variable voltage and/or PWM. Motors tend to not run very slow well. Controlling at a modest speed wth gearing helps. You can byt hobby motor + gearboxes for "not much". Using tachometer feedback will allow better low speed control in exchange for more complexity. Ask if of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-DC-motor-speed-control-potentiometer/

or any alternative. Its possible to use PWM too:
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/pulse-width-modulation.html

Answer (score 0):

Information is really incomplete but i will try to give it a shot.

I presume the motor is dc brush motor. If you are not that much good in electronics than a buy an arduino, linear potentiometer 10 and motor controller(many are available online i.e Sparkfun, Adafruit)

Here is how it will work

You will convert 12v supply to 5V using linear regulator LM7805 and feed it to Arduino. Its better to use seperate power supply for Arduino and Motor(Dont wana go in snubers, isolating power supply)

Now that your Arduino is up and running. Next step is to identify inputs and output.

Your input will be analog from Slider POT(Potentiometer) feed into Analog Input of Pin.  Output will be PWM to your motor controller.

Try searching Arduino DC motor speed control using POT on google and you will get alot of project.